# TSQL Azure SQL Server LEFT CHARINDEX

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, azure

I have a TSQL statement that queries a single table looking for duplicate street address numbers.  For example "123 Street" matches "123 St.".  I use CHARINDEX to separate the string by selecting the characters on the left of the string but before the space which are almost always numbers as seen below:

```
    "SELECT NewId() as NewId," +
            //We rename the dbo.User table as "a" then rename it again as "b" so we can look for duplicate Street Address numbers
            "a.Id AS LeftID,a.DateSubmitted AS LeftDateSubmitted,a.Updated AS LeftUpdated," +
            "a.Status AS LeftStatus,a.StreetAddress AS LeftStreetAddress," +

            "b.Id AS RightID,b.DateSubmitted AS RightDateSubmitted,b.Updated AS RightUpdated," +
            "b.Status AS RightStatus,b.StreetAddress AS RightStreetAddress " +

            //We join the 2 virtual dbo.User tables where table b Id's are greater than table a meaning b records are newer
            "FROM [User] a JOIN [User] b ON b.Id > a.Id AND " +

            //LEFT selects the left most characters (usually numbers) in the StreetAddress field string before the space ' '
            //and eliminates the rest of the address isolating just the street address numbers for matching
            "LEFT(a.StreetAddress,CHARINDEX(' ',a.StreetAddress)) = LEFT(b.StreetAddress,CHARINDEX(' ',b.StreetAddress)) " +

            //Don't show orange or blue status records
            "AND b.Status != 'Orange' AND a.Status != 'Orange' AND a.Status != 'Blue' AND b.Status != 'Blue' " +

            //If a b record (newer) is red then ignore because it is completed and ignore a records (oldest) older than 90 days
            "WHERE a.DateSubmitted >= (GetDate() - 90) AND b.Status != 'Red' " +

            //Show newest records first
            "ORDER BY b.DateSubmitted DESC"
```

This has been working fairly well until today it was noticed that false positives were being picked up if the person entered the address in all caps as seen below:
[image: Grid View]

My understanding of using:

```
    LEFT(a.StreetAddress,CHARINDEX(' ',a.StreetAddress))
```

Would result in the leftmost characters before the space being used for my JOIN yet the image above shows matches that should not occur? Please help an SQL beginner...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that the query you are sending to the database server to get those results is the exact query you are generating with that code.  Not only is it improperly matching addresses... you can also see that there are `ID` in `b` that are less than `a`.  Set a break-point where you are sending the query to the server and examine the query string and verify what you are really sending.

Comment: I appreciate the response but I am not sure the answer tells me much by saying the query isn't getting to the server.  What exactly would lead you to that determination?  Thanks Brian I will try the breakpoint.

Comment: I don't think the server is executing the query you shared with us because the string you seem to be building with that code does not match your results at all.  I don't think it's a problem with the query that you intended or the case of the strings in the data... I think it's a problem with the logistics of sending the correct string to the server.  I can't help you with that part with the information you have shared in your question.  It's not just matching addresses inappropriately... it's ignoring the part that joins on the IDs as well.

Comment: The thing is it has been working well for many months. It only got weird this week & only with addresses typed in all caps. That said it's understandable that with this limited information a direct answer is not likely attained. I was hoping the CHARINDEX and the all caps clue might ring a bell for someone but it could be a red herring.  Also even though there is concatenation in the SQL statement when I develop it it is a single line in VS 2015 & both results match.  But what is most important is your suggestion to add breakpoints which I am currently elucidating myself to. Ty Brian!